# What is the cause of io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException on deplyoment

Tags: java, ssl, javafx, netty, jpackage

So I'm developing a JavaFX app and when I run it on IntelliJ it works perfectly without any errors nor warnings but when I deploy it using Jpackage on sending WebSockets it throws the exception `io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException`
here's my Jpackage code

`jpackage -t exe --name "App Name" --description "App Description" --app-version 1.1.0 --input input --dest output --icon favicon.ico --main-jar app.jar --module-path Path\to\javafx-jmods-17.0.1 --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.base,javafx.graphics,javafx.web,javafx.fxml,java.sql,javafx.media --win-shortcut --win-menu --win-console`

I tried narrowing the error down and it looks like its caused by ChannelFuture.sync() although this only occurs during packaging of the jar

Am I missing a java option or an export that I overlooked by mistake?
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am currently facing a similar problem.

Comment: Not really, but i've noticed it has do with the network failing

Comment: @G.M if you are using secure websockets try adding in the --add-modules this jdk.crypto.cryptoki i believe its somehow responsible for sslhandshake issue that are causing the connection to close